# Why can't my code find my value even though i know it's there?

Tags: android, database, search

```
**Here im trying to confirm that if a value is found so that i can move to the next page.**     

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
    sqlStuff search1 = new sqlStuff(search_page.this);
    switch (arg0.getId()) {

    case R.id.search_button:


        boolean found = false;
        String Systname = editText1.getText().toString();


        String[] IDSysNames = search1.getIDSysName();
        for(int i = 0; i < IDSysNames.length; i++)
        {
            if(Systname.equals(IDSysNames[i].toString()))
            {
              found = true;
              number = i;
            }
        }



        if(found==true)
        {
         Intent search = new Intent("com.MC.ChemPal.RESULT");
         startActivity(search);

        }
        else
        {
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("result not found");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }
        break;
```

**This is the part where i try to get the value below**

```
public String[] getIDSysName()
{
    String[] result = new String[0];

    try
    {
        String[] columns = new String[] {KEY_SYSNAME };
        Cursor c  =  ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,  null, null, null, null);
        int iSysName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SYSNAME);

        int i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            i++;
        }

        result = new String[i];
        i = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            result[i] = c.getString(iSysName);
            String lk = null;
            Log.d(lk, result[i]);
                            i++;
        }

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
      String tr = null;
          Log.e(tr, e.getMessage());    
    }

    return result;
}
```

This code is supposed to check my database for a value and if it's found move to a next  page. But i keep getting the dialog for the value not found i added. I have checked that the value is there as i have a database view code as well.

Log cat.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION:MAIN
java.lang.NullPointerException:println needs a message
at android.util.Log.printlnNative(Native Method)
at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:230)
at com.MC.ChemPal.SqlDStuff.getIDSysName(sqlStuff.java.153)
at com.MC.ChemPal.search_page.onClick(search_page.java:42)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java.2485)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java.9080)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(zygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: use log.d to print the value when you perform searching.it will give u exact idea about what is happening.

Comment: log causes error for some reason

Comment: sorry it took so long to add

Comment: you are having Null Pointer at line number 153 of sqlStuff.java .which is line number 153 please check it,it might resides in getIDSysName() method.

Comment: line 153 is within the exception part of that method  where i've place the log.

Comment: update your question with newly added log in your code

Comment: Check if your `ourDatabase` is not null object.

Comment: add `Log.d("SqlDStuff", "Cursor count: "+c.getCount());` after `Cursor c  =  ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,  null, null, null, null);`

Answer (score 0):

Here's your problem:

```
  String tr = null;
  Log.e(tr, e.getMessage());
```

The first argument to Log.e should be a String object containing a TAG. Try this instead:

```
  String tr = "My Tag";
  Log.e(tr, e.getMessage());
```

I think that you are getting an error somewhere in your database code, but the crash here is being caused by your exception handling.

Comment: hi,Your point is fine as per standard practices but I have tested as I was curious about such mistake,and I found something weird.it doesn't give error if `Log.e(null,"value");` but it gives error when `Log.e("tag",null);`.

Comment: i've got it finding the results now i had to put a database.open() and close(); either side of the search object

Answer (score 0):

log causes error due to the reason specified by `Mark Allison`.
If your code was working fine before adding the logs,the root of the problem of not getting searched item may be the Case Sensitive search.

try to use

```
Systname.equalsIgnoreCase(IDSysNames[i].toString())
```

instead of

```
Systname.equals(IDSysNames[i].toString())
```

Comment: i tried the ignore case thing and it did nothing but is still useful and i tried adding the log d and altering the tr value but i still got an error. and ourDatabase is set up as private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase; any more ideas guys cus im still stumped.

Comment: did you check your `Cursor count` ?

Comment: using the log d yeh but i'm getting errors still and it just doesnt register